# XSLT create copies of source messages with single instances of inner structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to find a generic xslt transformation that could solve this problem.
Assume to have this XML

```
<Train>
    <GeneralData>
        <TrainNumber>123</TrainNumber>
    </GeneralData>
    <ArrayOfCoaches>
        <Coach>
            <CoachNumber>1</CoachNumber>
            <CoachSeats>18</CoachSeats>
        </Coach>
        <Coach>
            <CoachNumber>2</CoachNumber>
            <CoachSeats>23</CoachSeats>
        </Coach>
        <Coach>
            <CoachNumber>3</CoachNumber>
            <CoachSeats>34</CoachSeats>
        </Coach>
    </ArrayOfCoaches>
</Train>
```

I would like to be able to "split" this message creating several  sections containing only one Coach like this

```
<ArrayOfTrainCoaches>
    <Train>
        <GeneralData>
            <TrainNumber>123</TrainNumber>
        </GeneralData>
        <ArrayOfCoaches>
            <Coach>
                <CoachNumber>1</CoachNumber>
                <CoachSeats>18</CoachSeats>
            </Coach>
        </ArrayOfCoaches>
    </Train>
    <Train>
        <GeneralData>
            <TrainNumber>123</TrainNumber>
        </GeneralData>
        <ArrayOfCoaches>
            <Coach>
                <CoachNumber>2</CoachNumber>
                <CoachSeats>23</CoachSeats>
            </Coach>
        </ArrayOfCoaches>
    </Train>
    <Train>
        <GeneralData>
            <TrainNumber>123</TrainNumber>
        </GeneralData>
        <ArrayOfCoaches>
            <Coach>
                <CoachNumber>3</CoachNumber>
                <CoachSeats>34</CoachSeats>
            </Coach>
        </ArrayOfCoaches>
    </Train>
</ArrayOfTrainCoaches>
```

It's not clear to me how to use for-each for duplicate the whole message except some substructure that I want to split in dedicated copies of the whole message.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like:

```
<ArrayOfTrainCoaches>
  <xsl:for-each select="//Coach">
    <Train>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//GeneralData"/>
        <ArrayOfCoaches>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </ArrayOfCoaches>
    </Train>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ArrayOfTrainCoaches>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Train">
        <ArrayOfTrainCoaches>
        <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfCoaches/Coach">

            <Train>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Train/GeneralData"/>
                <ArrayOfCoaches>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </ArrayOfCoaches>
            </Train>

        </xsl:for-each>
            </ArrayOfTrainCoaches>
    </xsl:template>
Look it
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you too! I'll try also your suggestion!